# putstr() is not defined in SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, shell, spidermonkey

I've installed Spider Monkey in my OS(Ubuntu 16.04 x64).

> SpiderMonkey is Mozilla's JavaScript engine written in C/C++. It is used in various Mozilla products, including Firefox, and is available under the MPL2.  --- [Mozilla's Developer Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey)

I am learning [O'REILLY Data Structure and Algorithm with JavaScript](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/data-structures-and/9781449373931/pr01.html) now. And I can use `print()` method correctly in my shell. But when I use `putstr()` method, there exists an error: `putstr() is not defined.`

In the [Shell global objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Shell_global_objects) website, I learned that `putstr()` is a global objects. And why it is not defined in my shell?  My SpiderMonkey version is 1.7.0.

Comment: Works fine for me. How are you running the shell?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the shell, and not, say, JS in the Firefox browser console? I just unzipped the latest nightly binary build from [here](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-central/jsshell-linux-x86_64.zip), ran it, and `putstr` was there and functional.

Comment: For example, I just type "putstr("Enter you key words")", then the shell gives me an error: `putstr is not defiend.` What is your SpiderMonkey version? And is there something wrong with my installment?

Comment: I do again as you said, but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: > How are you running the shell?